# Heroku and Node.js

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am quite new to node.js so i am just trying to understand someone's code and re-produce the web app in Heroku.

However, I am getting the 404 status when I try to verify the webhook.

```
2021-05-21T05:36:57.966963+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-05-21T05:37:00.888075+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-21T05:37:00.888096+00:00 app[web.1]: > lineagem2@0.0.0 start /app
2021-05-21T05:37:00.888096+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./bin/www
2021-05-21T05:37:00.888096+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-21T05:37:01.303644+00:00 app[web.1]: connecting successful
2021-05-21T05:37:01.777725+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-05-21T05:37:47.370204+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/callback" host=lineage-m-boss.herokuapp.com request_id=4a6c62dc-d71d-478f-974b-88b165309b54 fwd="147.92.150.194" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=45ms status=404 bytes=248 protocol=https
```

This is my index.js in my Express routes

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

// POST method route
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Please help me as I am not sure what went wrong. I can provide my main.js if needed.

Comment: Have you created a Procfile?

Comment: Cannot see '/callback' router in index.js file. The webhook is trying to call host/callback it seems..  Not sure whether you defined it correctly router.post('/callback', function (req, res, next) {

Comment: @zx01 no, do I need one? on the Heroku build, I saw it use the default which built the web app. that is what I wanted too

Comment: @RiteshKumarGupta I feel I am missing defining the callback but I am not sure I should add it in the Route index.js or my main.js file